# Angular Directive - can I have an isolate scope inherit from parent?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, isolate-scope

I am trying to edit an angular directive written by somebody else and I am coming across an issue. It is an attribute directive and I want to watch the value passed in as the attribute's value for changes.

This works when I give it an isolate scope and watch the property using scope.$watch. However using an isolate scope breaks the directive as it had the scope set to true originally which it needs for other things (as I understand it means it inherits the parent scope).

So my question is, how can I inherit the parent scope, but also watch the attribute's value?

To help clarify, here is a basic example of the directive:

```
return {
            scope: {
                myGridsterItem: "=gridsterItem"
            },
            restrict: 'EA',
            controller: 'GridsterItemCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'gridsterItem',
            require: ['^gridster', 'gridsterItem'],
            link: function(scope, $el, attrs, controllers) {

                .....

                // need to dynamically update draggable/resizable of individuaol gridster item if properties change
                scope.$watch("myGridsterItem.draggable", function(newVal) {
                    draggable.updateDraggable(newVal);
                }, true);
                scope.$watch("myGridsterItem.resizable", function(newVal) {
                    resizable.updateResizable(newVal);
                }, true);

                .....
            }
    }
```

This throws an error due to it not inheriting the parent scope. And if I set

```
scope: true
```

My error is solved, but the watch handlers never run.

A rough outline of the HTML:

```
<div gridster="gridsterOpts">
    <ul>
        <li gridster-item="getPrefs(portlet.id)", ng-repeat="portlet in getPortlets()">
            .....
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Updated answer

I've had more of a play and demonstrated one possible solution in a code snippet below.

Without using an isolated scope (as this caused other issues for you), basically what we need is for `getPrefs(portlet.id)` to get interpolated or parsed when your directive's link function tries to assign it to scope. Without doing this, if you output the value of `attrs.gridsterItem` to console you'll see it's `getPrefs(portlet.id)`, and not the result of calling that function.

The cleanest-looking solution I came across was to use [`$parse`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse). Within your link function, it allows us to evaluate the function contained in the attribute at the time we're assigning it to scope. This way it's the result of that function that gets assigned, which allows the watcher functions to fire correctly.

Note that `$parse` has to be added as a dependency to the directive declaration and passed as a parameter.

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var myApp = angular.module("myApp", [])
    .directive("gridsterItem", ["$parse", GridsterItemDirective]); // Make sure to DI '$parse'

  function GridsterItemDirective($parse) {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      controller: 'GridsterItemCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'gridsterItem',
      require: ['^gridster', 'gridsterItem'],
      link: function(scope, $el, attrs, controllers) {
        scope.output = ""; //for demo'ing
        scope.myGridsterItem = $parse(attrs.gridsterItem)(scope); //evaluating the value of attrs.gridsterItem in the context of 'scope'

        // need to dynamically update draggable/resizable of individuaol gridster item if properties change
        scope.$watch("myGridsterItem.draggable", function(newVal) {
          console.log("myGridsterItem.draggable: ", newVal);
          scope.output += "Draggable updated (" + newVal + ")... ";
        }, true);
        scope.$watch("myGridsterItem.resizable", function(newVal) {
          console.log("myGridsterItem.resizable: ", newVal);
          scope.output += "Resizable updated (" + newVal + ")... ";
        }, true);
      }
    };
  }

  //-------------------------------
  //Supporting mockups...
  myApp.controller("myController", ["$scope", MyController]) //supporting mocks
    .directive("gridster", [GridsterDirective])
    .controller("GridsterCtrl", ["$scope", GridsterCtrl])
    .controller("GridsterItemCtrl", ["$scope", GridsterItemCtrl]);

  function MyController($scope) {
    var _portlets = [{
      id: "1"
    }, {
      id: "2"
    }, {
      id: "3"
    }];

    $scope.getPortlets = function getPortlets() {
      return _portlets;
    };

    var _prefs = {
      "1": {
        draggable: true,
        resizable: true
      },
      "2": {
        draggable: true,
        resizable: true
      },
      "3": {
        draggable: true,
        resizable: true
      },
    };
    $scope.getPrefs = function getPrefs(id) {
      return _prefs[id];
    }
    $scope.setPrefs = function setPrefs(id, prefName, value) {
      _prefs[id][prefName] = value;
    }
  }

  function GridsterDirective() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      controller: 'GridsterCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'gridster'
    };
  }

  function GridsterCtrl($scope) {
    //mock
  }

  function GridsterItemCtrl($scope) {
    //mock
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  li {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    font: 0.8em Arial, sans-serif;
  }
</style>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <div gridster>
      <ul>
        <li gridster-item="getPrefs(portlet.id)" ng-repeat="portlet in getPortlets()">
          <p><strong>portlet.id:</strong> {{portlet.id}}</p>
          <p>{{getPrefs(portlet.id)}}</p>
          <p><strong>Output:</strong> {{output}}</p>
          <button ng-click="setPrefs(portlet.id, 'draggable', !getPrefs(portlet.id).draggable)">Toggle Draggable</button>
          <button ng-click="setPrefs(portlet.id, 'resizable', !getPrefs(portlet.id).resizable)">Toggle Resizable</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***Old Answer:***

Within your link function (with non-isolated scope), try this:

```
scope.myGridsterItem = attrs.gridsterItem;
```

`attrs` is a param that has been automatically provided to your link function, and should contain within it a collection of the attributes on the element your directive has been used upon. Get the attribute you need, and assign it to a scope variable that matches the relevant ones in the $watch expressions (`myGridsterItem` in this case, it looks like).

Remember that angular's naming conventions mean that an attribute called `this-is-an-attribute` in the HTML will be accessible as `thisIsAnAttribute` (snake- to camel-case conversion) in the javascript.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work as the watch handlers still do not run. I also tried using scope.myGridsterItem = scope.$eval(attrs.gridsterItem)

Comment: Actually, I've ended up recommending using `$parse` which is essentially what you were trying with `scope.$eval`; in fact, if you edit my snippet and replace the `$parse` line with the one you've mentioned in your comment above, it appears to also work. So I'm thinking there may be more to this. Perhaps still worth trying `$parse` and letting me know your results?

Comment: I've copied my test code into a Plnkr so it's easier to fork and play with, in case you want to experiment: http://plnkr.co/edit/UmdPrvmHr90cd4wE9ctu?p=preview

Comment: Can I confirm - angular version?

Comment: It is 1.2.28 - I ended up implementing a workaround, but when I get time I will go back and check if using $parse works, thanks. Part of my problem may be that the ng-repeat was running on a function's return value, but I'm not sure if changing that was just a coincidence.